# Get members of Windows Group with Python

Tags: python, windows, winapi, active-directory

How do I get the members of a Windows group (Active Directory, probably) using Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [active_directory](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/ad_cookbook.html) module.

Example taken from the above website:

```
import active_directory

for user in active_directory.search ("objectCategory='Person'", "objectClass='User'"):
    print user
```